# How do i make a delete function in my php code

Tags: php

I have school order. I need to create a delete function on a application that they made. I dont know how to make this at the moment. I know how to make a CRUD system in laravel, but this is plain PHP.

```
 private function add() 
 {    $klantId = -1;
      if (isset($_POST['inputklanten'])) 
      {
           $klantId = $_POST['inputklanten'];
      }
      $row = $this->getKlantVars($klantId); 
      $rowreservering = $this->getReserveringVars(-1);
      $row = array_merge($row, $rowreservering);

      $output = "
           <form action='?action=add' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

                <label>Selecteer klant
                </label>

                <select id='inputklanten' name='inputklanten'>" .
                     $this->getKlanten() . "                         
                </select> 

                <input type='submit' name='submit_klantselecteren' 
                       id='submit_klantselecteren' value='Selecteer klant'/>
      </form>" .

      $this->showReserveringForm($row);

      return $output;   
 }

 protected function edit()
 {
      $reserveringId = -1;
      if (isset($_GET['reservering'])) 
      {
           $reserveringId = $_GET['reservering'];
      }

      $row = $this->getReserveringVars($reserveringId); 
      $klantId = $row['klant_id'];
      $rowklant = $this->getKlantVars($klantId); 
      $row = array_merge($row, $rowklant);

      $output = $this->showReserveringForm($row);

      return $output;
 }
```

Above here you can see an `edit` and `add` functions they made. I hope someone can help me out with this problem.

At the moment this is my delete function. It works and shows the echo when I'm clicking on the delete button with the id in the url

```
     protected function delete() 
 {
      $output = "delete gevonden";
      return $output;
 }
```

Comment: I think no one is going to help you if you haven't tried it by yourself first ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected function delete()
{
    $reserveringId = -1;
    if (isset($_GET['reservering']))
    {
        $reserveringId = $_GET['reservering'];
    }

    // sql to delete a record
    $sql = ("DELETE FROM `reservering` WHERE `reservering`.`reservering_id` = '$reserveringId';");

    if ($this->connection->query($sql)) {
        $output = "Reservering is succesvol verwijderd";
        return $output;
    } else {
        $output = "Het is niet gelukt om de reservering te verwijderen";
        return $output;
    }
}
```

I did it peeps thanks for helping :)

Comment: Glad you sorted it, but... **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Answer (score 0):

Example function, but you have to learn.

```
function delete_products($id) {
    global $db;


    $sql = "DELETE FROM products ";
    $sql .= "WHERE id='" . db_escape($db, $id) . "' ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    // For DELETE statements, $result is true/false
    if($result) {
      return true;
    } else {
      // DELETE failed
      echo mysqli_error($db);
      db_disconnect($db);
      exit;
    }
  }
```

OO

```
  public function delete() {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM " . static::$table_name . " ";
    $sql .= "WHERE id='" . self::$database->escape_string($this->id) . "' ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result = self::$database->query($sql);
    return $result;
```

Comment: Better to use proper parameterised queries and prepared statements than some homemade (and, in this answer, undefined) db_escape() function. Let the database library take care of security and sanitisation properly. There's a good chance this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and maybe unexpected syntax errors

Comment: Also...global database objects? In 2019? This code looks like something from the days of PHP4

Comment: If someone does not understand it, will not understand OO ` public function delete() {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM " . static::$table_name . " ";`